Is it possible to create an Android Foreground service for location monitoring in Android 14 that won't close when the application is closed?
I'm developing a monitoring application on MAUI Blazor for Android 14. Is it possible to make the monitoring (GPS Location) continue working even if the application is closed from the recent tasks?
There are many examples of foreground service on the internet, but none of them work in a way that continues to receive coordinates when the application is closed. I'm currently actively studying the shiny.net library. The application is legitimate, so any kind of user notifications are acceptable. Thank you.
